# Combining two similar SQL queries

Tags: postgresql

I'm using the following SQL query twice with different values of `limit`. In my case, 40 and 100, though it doesn't really matter. My question is - can I combine these two queries into one query? It would probably be faster. `sample` is a PG array.

I don't know how much more information is needed, but if you need more details, please ask. I'm reluctant to add details about the schema unless necessary, since it will make the question much longer.

```
SELECT   SUM(motif)
FROM     (SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY crossvalnum ORDER BY crossvalnum, pvalue DESC, margstat) AS r,
                    (seqindex IS NOT NULL)::INTEGER                                                        AS motif,
                    crossval.crossvalnum,
                    data.margstat,
                    data.pvalue
         FROM       data
                    INNER JOIN datasubgroup
                    ON         data.datasubgroup_id=datasubgroup.id
                    INNER JOIN crossval
                    ON         datasubgroup.crossval_id=crossval.id
         WHERE      data.seqindex                      =ANY(crossval.sample)
         OR         data.seqindex                  IS NULL
         )
         AS q
WHERE    q.r <= limit
GROUP BY crossvalnum;
```

The value for 40 is

```
sum 
-----
  25
  22
  19
  16
  24
(5 rows)
```

The value for 100 is

```
sum 
-----
  32
  28
  24
  23
  31
(5 rows)
```

Update: `motif` is defined an an indicator variable, `(seqindex IS NOT NULL)::INTEGER`. The `SUM` corresponds with the `GROUP BY crossvalnum` as an aggregate query. So the sum happens across each crossvalnum group. So there is a window function inside an aggregate query. I want the output to be two columns.

Comment: Can you edit the query so it's obvious which table the `crossvalnum, margstat, etc.` columns are in?

Comment: And what you want as output. 5 rows and 2 columns?

Comment: What is the `SUM(motif)` supposed to do? Count the number of rows that `seqindex` is not null?

Comment: @ypercube Yes. `motif` is defined an an indicator variable. `(seqindex IS NOT NULL)::INTEGER`. The SUM corresponds with the GROUP BY `crossvalnum` as an aggregate query. So the sum happens across each crossvalnum group. So there is a window function inside an aggregate query. The query itself could quite possibly be improved, but it does work for me. Question edited as requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will it work for you ?

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN r <=LEAST(40,100) THEN motif ELSE 0 END) as sum1,
SUM(motif) as sum2
FROM (...) q  -- or AS q , whatever version you prefer
WHERE    q.r <= GREATEST(40,100)
GROUP BY crossvalnum;
```

Comment: That works well thanks, though I don't yet understand *why* it works. :-)

Comment: @Faheem Mitha : you are passing 2 numbers (say 100 and 40) , one number is greater than another, so condition `q.r <= greatest` which is `q.r <=100` also returns everything you need for `q.r<=40`; thus, you have one sum (`sum2`) naturally with just `SUM(motif)`. To get second sum (`sum1`) you need to ignore records where r is between 41 and 100 which is done with `CASE`...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. BTW, I think the query needs a `AS q` after `FROM (...)`.

Comment: Sure it should be there... Sorry, typo. Fixing.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, the query does a count in `greatest-n-per-row` type of query where `n` takes 2 values (40 and 100).

This can probably be solved better by rewriting the subquery. The easier to write might be to do a join of two queries:

```
SELECT
    a.motif AS cntA, b.motif AS cntB, a.crossvalnum
FROM
    (query with limit = 40) AS a
  JOIN
    (query with limit = 100) AS b
      ON b.crossvalnum = a.crossvalnum ;
```

Here is another way by moving the counts inside the subquery:

```
SELECT   MIN(motif) AS cntA,
         MAX(motif) AS cntB,
         crossvalnum
FROM     (SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                        ( PARTITION BY crossvalnum 
                          ORDER BY crossvalnum, pvalue DESC, margstat
                        ) AS r,
                    COUNT(*) OVER 
                        ( PARTITION BY crossvalnum 
                        ) AS c,
                    COUNT(seqindex) OVER 
                        ( PARTITION BY crossvalnum 
                          ORDER BY crossvalnum, pvalue DESC, margstat
                          ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                        ) AS motif,
                    crossval.crossvalnum
         FROM       data
                    INNER JOIN datasubgroup
                    ON         data.datasubgroup_id=datasubgroup.id
                    INNER JOIN crossval
                    ON         datasubgroup.crossval_id=crossval.id
         WHERE      data.seqindex                      =ANY(crossval.sample)
         OR         data.seqindex                  IS NULL
         )
         AS q 
WHERE    r IN (LEAST(c, @limitA), LEAST(c, @limitB)) 
GROUP BY crossvalnum ;
```

Comment: For the second query, I get `ERROR:  count(*) must be used to call a parameterless aggregate function
LINE 8:                     COUNT() OVER`. Once `COUNT()` is changed to `COUNT(*)`, it works, thanks.